# how to add two disks as raid1 in existing ubuntu 12 server

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I have Ubuntu 12 server running on a usb stick.  I have one 2tb HD (B) and one 1 TB (C)that I want to configure in a RAID1 configuration.
 I want to partition the 2 tb drive into 4 equal sized partitions, I want to configure the 1 tb drive into 4 equal sized partitions.  The partitions in B are .5 tb, the partitions in C are .25 TB.  I want to mirror B,part0 to C,part0, and B,part1 to C,part1.

Is this possible to do? What are the steps to do this using ubuntu,mdadm?

Do the partitions have to be the same size on each HD to be mirrored?

The C HD is a temporary place holder till I can get another 2tb disk, but I still want to set up and mirror the data...I can guarantee that that data will never be more than 0.20 TB (until I get a larger C drive) so I won't exceed the partition space on the C drive.

Thanks for any help

-J

Answer (score 0):

In regards to sizes of your drives. It is recommended that you will use partitions of same sizes when creating RAID1. Otherwise you will waste space on bigger partition.

In regards to how to add the RAID - yes you can use mdadm. Steps for that procedure could be found very easy. This is [one example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-software-raid-one-arrays/).

There is possibility to create "broken RAID" using just one Hard Drive. You can set it up like that using just one HD and when you will get your another HD of same size you just add it to RAID so that system will mirror data to second hard drive. At this point you will have fully operational RAID1 without wasted space. You can do that if you feel that you will gain something from it.